# How to "shrink" a Java 8 stream from many entries to fewer

Tags: java, functional-java

How can I "shrink" a Java 8 stream containing a lot of items to a stream containing fewer?

I am not asking about mapping, where there's 1 "output" item for each input item, or reduction where a stream is reduced to a single value, but shrinking a stream of many items to one with fewer. The "shrinking" is stateful; emitting an item is based upon 1 or more previous items (though it's simply moving forward so the state is very simple).

I have a stream of simple timestamped events; either a START or STOP event. I need to reduce this stream of simple events into records, each comprising a start and stop time. In the simplest case, there is a START and STOP pair, but it is totally legal for there to be repeated STARTs without intervening STOPs. It's also legal, though degenerate, for there to be repeated STOPs.

Below is a (simplified) version to demonstrate. See the difference between `input` and `expected`; there are more input items than output.

The key thing is that shrinkEvents signature is in terms of Streams, not Lists. I would like a version that doesn't need the intermediate `List<String> output` in `shrinkEvents`.

```java
public class ShrinkStream {
    @Test
    public void shrinkStream() {
        Stream<String> input = Stream.of("START@1", "STOP@12", "START@14", "START@24", "STOP@35", "STOP@45");
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("1-12", "14-24", "24-35");

        Stream<String> actual = shrinkEvents(input);

        assertEquals(expected, actual.collect(toList()));
    }

    private Stream<String> shrinkEvents(Stream<String> input) {
        List<String> output = new ArrayList<>();

        final StringBuilder startTime = new StringBuilder(); // mutable (effectively final BS)
        input.forEach(s -> {
            String[] tokens = s.split("@");
            String type = tokens[0];
            String time = tokens[1];

            boolean isAlreadyActive = startTime.length() > 0;
            if (isAlreadyActive)
                output.add(startTime + "-" + time);

            startTime.setLength(0); // reset

            if (type.equals("START"))
                startTime.append(time);
        });

        return output.stream();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just in case this is more than just an exercise: there are [Complex Event Processing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_Event_Processing) engines that do exactly what you implement: aggregate events to higher level events. I used [Esper](http://www.espertech.com/esper/) once. They have a language where you define the output event as *many starts and one stop generate event foo*.Then you only consume the output stream of aggregated events without working on the input events.

Comment: Thanks, that was an interesting read, but I don't need anything that complex for my simple program. It's a real thing not an exercise but really very simple with just the 2 events.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [flatMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) which would produce empty stream for beginning of the pair and a single-entry stream for the end of the pair.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of a string is to examine the elements inside the Stream independently for others without the concern of processing the element in order.

In this scenario, your ask is a little stretch because we need to keep track of the previous "START" element.
The more correct way that I see is to use a Custom Collector.

```java
public class ShrinkStream {
    @Test
    public void shrinkStream() {
        Stream<String> input = Stream.of("START@1", "STOP@12", "START@14", "START@24", "STOP@35", "STOP@45").parallel();
        List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("1-12", "14-24", "24-35");

        MyShrinkCollector myShrinkCollector= new MyShrinkCollector();
        assertEquals(expected, input.collect(myShrinkCollector));
    } 
}
```

```java
public class MyShrinkCollector implements Collector<String, List<String>, List<String>> {

    private String startNumber = null;

    @Override
    public Supplier<List<String>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<String>, String> accumulator() {
        return (list, val) -> {
            String[] s = val.split("@");
            String type = s[0];
            String num = s[1];

            if (startNumber != null) {
                list.add(startNumber + "-" + num);
                startNumber = null;
            }

            if (type.equals("START")) startNumber = num;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<String>> combiner() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<String>, List<String>> finisher() {
        return Function.identity();
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, but I'm looking for a method that maps a stream into another stream of (fewer) records. `MyShrinkCollector` will return a collection. I know I can call `stream()` on that collection, but that's not the idea.

Comment: I've never used `parallelStream` but use sequential `stream` all the time as a nice way of breaking down a problem. So I understand your comment but I'm not worried about them being processed out-of-order. Though that does explain why what I'm asking for isn't available.